# Display short title and long title (both) in a caption?

Tags: formatting, captions, koma-script

The syntax for a caption is

```
\caption[listoffigures/tables text]{Text actually displayed under picture/table}
```

But what I would like to have is something like this: If I use the above command, the text under the floating object should be

```
Label #.: listof text -- long text
```

With `#` being just the number and with `--` being an arbitrary separator (either the `--` dash itself or maybe even a `\newline`). Is this possible?

I'm using KOMAScript.

Comment: ... and if no `[]` is given?

Comment: Just the long text, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the commented code. If you load any float-related packages (`float`, `floatrow`, `caption`, `algorithmic`, ...) or do things like `\newfloat`, `\restylefloat` etc., *this my tweak must come **after** all that.*

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\makeatletter
\let\x@caption\caption % original \caption
\def\x@@caption[#1]#2{\x@caption[{#1}]{#1 --- #2}} % with optional arg
\def\x@@@caption#1{\x@caption[{#1}]{#1}} % without optional arg
\def\caption{\@ifnextchar[\x@@caption\x@@@caption} % new \caption
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\caption[Optional text.]{Obligatory text.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\caption{Obligatory text only.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `\x@` or`\x@@`, etc... The number of `@` is for what?

Comment: @Sigur the character `@` behaves like a letter between `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`, therefore all three strings `\x@caption`, ... are just macro names. Further reading: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/11002

Comment: @yo' -  I think you should explain a little better what you are doing. From what I was able to tell the `\makeatletter` environment is only necessary so you can use `\@ifnextchar`. You didn't have to define those other variable with `@`s. The rest I think I understand.