# Display short title and long title (both) in a caption with subcaption

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, subcaption

I am trying to use the tweak provided in [Display short title and long title (both) in a caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91341/display-short-title-and-long-title-both-in-a-caption) together with the subcaption package.

Unfortunatelly it breaks:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\makeatletter
\let\x@caption\caption % original \caption
\def\x@@caption[#1]#2{\x@caption[{#1}]{#1 --- #2}} % with optional arg
\def\x@@@caption#1{\x@caption[{#1}]{#1}} % without optional arg
\def\caption{\@ifnextchar[\x@@caption\x@@@caption} % new \caption
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\caption[Optional text.]{Obligatory text.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\caption{Obligatory text only.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I am using many subfigures in my document, so going away from the subcaption package is no alternative.

**Edit:**

Using the caption package with option `\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}` does produce figure captions of the intended format (Optional text. -- Obligatory text.) with the corresponding list of figures entry (Optional text.). Thanks to TeXnician for the remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more than one way to cause caption to behave differently in different floats.  The usual way is to set and test `\@captype`, but one can also simply redefine `\caption` inside the float.  This appears to be the approach used by KOMA.  So you just need to reset it back again.

Note: the `##1` is to not confuse it with the `#1` argument for `\captionreset`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\captionreset}{%
  \let\x@caption\caption % original (caption package) \caption
  \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\empty]{\ifx\empty##1\relax\x@caption{##2}%
    \else\x@caption[##1]{##1 -- ##2}%
    \fi}% new \caption
}
\let\x@figure=\figure % original figure
\renewcommand{\figure}{\x@figure\captionreset}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\caption[Optional text.]{Obligatory text.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\caption{Obligatory text only.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

From the KOMA source I found that `\caption` was being replaced by either `\captionabove` or `\captionbelow`.  So a simpler solution would be to replace those in the preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\let\x@caption\caption% original (caption package) \caption
\newcommand{\x@@caption}[2][\empty]{%
  \ifx\empty#1\relax\x@caption{#2}%
  \else\x@caption[#1]{#1 -- #2}%
  \fi}% modified caption
\let\caption\x@@caption% new global \caption for other float types
\renewcommand{\captionabove}[2][\empty]{\captionsetup{position=above}%
  \x@@caption[#1]{#2}%
}% new \captionabove
\renewcommand{\captionbelow}[2][\empty]{\captionsetup{position=below}%
  \x@@caption[#1]{#2}%
}% new \captionbelow
\makeatother
```

Comment: Only remaining problem: I have no clue how this might work with lstlistings with enabled float... but for figures and tables this is perfect!

Comment: I found a simpler solution.

Comment: how can we make this work with `report` class ?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă - The OP code should work with report class.  It is KOMA that makes it difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to disable compatibility mode. This works:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\makeatletter
\let\x@caption\caption % original \caption
\def\x@@caption[#1]#2{\x@caption[{#1}]{#1 --- #2}} % with optional arg
\def\x@@@caption#1{\x@caption[{#1}]{#1}} % without optional arg
\def\caption{\@ifnextchar[\x@@caption\x@@@caption} % new \caption
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\caption[Optional text.]{Obligatory text.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{5cm}{5cm}
\caption{Obligatory text only.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I already tried this: Then the [Optional text] does not show up in the figure caption as intended

Comment: Than: `\caption[Text in LOF.]{Text in LOF. Some more text.}` ...

Comment: I don't like this approach since then I have to write the text twice. This is vulnerable to errors