# How to redefine caption in KOMA-Script to captionbeside?

Tags: captions, koma-script, lua

While experimenting with KOMA-Script's features I have found `captionbeside`. That's a really great option for me as I want my captions to be formatted this way. The only problem is that in a long document of mine I do not want to rewrite every figure.

So the question is how I could automatically change (by redefinition):

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{}
\caption{Blub}
\end{figure}
```

to be treated as

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{captionbeside}{Blub}
\includegraphics{}
\end{captionbeside}
\end{figure}
```

If it helps, I use LuaLaTeX, so a Lua solution would be okay too (although I would prefer LaTeX).

Complete code example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=10\baselineskip]{example-image}
        \caption{Test a}\label{testa}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{captionbeside}{Test b}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=10\baselineskip]{example-image}
            \label{testb}
        \end{captionbeside}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

*Update:* I have redefined `figure` to gobble captions. In that sense `captionbeside` works, but it of course won't output the right caption. How could I realize this (using the parameter of a not-yet-issued macro)?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\let\oldfigure\figure
\let\oldendfigure\endfigure
\renewenvironment{figure}{
    \oldfigure\let\caption\@gobble
        \begin{captionbeside}{Figure}
}{\end{captionbeside}\oldendfigure}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=10\baselineskip]{example-image}
        \caption{Test a}\label{testa}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=10\baselineskip]{example-image}
        \caption{Test b}\label{testb}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have much time right now, but: You might redefine the `figure`-environment to include the `captionbeside`-environment. The issue with redefining the `\caption` command might be a little tricky. Maybe a two run solution does work.

Comment: @Skillmon Well I thought about redefining the `figure` environment, but have no clue how I would capture the argument of `\caption` to be given to `captionbeside`. A two-run-solution would be fine for me.

Comment: The problem is that KOMA replaces \caption with either \captionabove or \captionbelow.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353986/display-short-title-and-long-title-both-in-a-caption-with-subcaption/354053?s=1|0.0910#354053

Comment: @JohnKormylo Then one would have to replace both of them. Do you know a smart redefinition?

Comment: Both `\captionabove` and `\captionbelow` call the same macro (`\scr@caption`), they set a boolean switch for the formatting behavior (if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to redefine `\caption` (and `\captionabove` and `\captionbelow`) to store the values and use them as arguments of the `captionbeside` environment. In the example below I also store the argument of `\label` to make it possible to have (exactly one) `\label` in the environment instead of in the `\caption` argument.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newsavebox\figurebox
\makeatletter
\let\truefigure\figure
\let\endtruefigure\endfigure
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{figure}{ o }{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\figurebox}%
    \begin{varwidth}[b]{\linewidth}
      \global\let\mandatorycaptionarg\relax
      \RenewDocumentCommand{\caption}{om}{%
        \ifx\mandatorycaptionarg\relax
          \IfNoValueTF{##1}%
            {\gdef\optionalcaptionarg{##2}}%
            {\gdef\optionalcaptionarg{##1}}%
          \gdef\mandatorycaptionarg{##2}%
        \else
          \@latex@warning{caption lost.\MessageBreak
            This implementation of `figure' supports only\MessageBreak
            one \string\caption\space per environment.\MessageBreak
            `\string\caption' ignored%
          }%
        \fi
      }%
      \RenewDocumentCommand{\label}{m}{%
        \ifx\labelarg\relax
          \gdef\labelarg{##1}%
        \else
          \@latex@warning{label lost.\MessageBreak
            This implementation of `figure' supports only\MessageBreak
            one \string\label\space per environment.\MessageBreak
            `\string\label' ignored%
          }%
        \fi
      }%
      \global\let\labelarg\relax
      \let\captionabove\caption
      \let\captionbelow\caption
}{%
    \end{varwidth}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \def\caption{%
    \if@figurecaptionabove\expandafter\captionabove
    \else\expandafter\captionbelow\fi
  }%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}%
    {\truefigure}%
    {\truefigure[#1]}%
  \begin{captionbeside}[\optionalcaptionarg]{\mandatorycaptionarg}%
    \usebox\figurebox
  \end{captionbeside}%
  \ifx\labelarg\relax\else\label{\labelarg}\fi%
  \endtruefigure
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=10\baselineskip]{example-image}
        \caption{Test a\label{testB}}\label{testA}% will work
%        \caption{Onther caption}% will be ignored (see warning in log)
    \end{figure}
    \begin{truefigure}
        \begin{captionbeside}{Test b\label{testa}}% \label will work
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=10\baselineskip]{example-image}
            \label{testb}% will not work
        \end{captionbeside}
        \label{testc}% will work
    \end{truefigure}

    See figures~\ref{testA} and \ref{testB} or \ref{testa}, \ref{testb},
    \ref{testc}.
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I've only solved the problem with the `\label` in your example. But note that you cannot have more than one `\caption` or more than one `\label` (outside `\caption`) in such a `figure`. If you need multi-caption figures you have to use `truefigure` now.

The `varwidth` if useful if you have vertical material (`\par`) in the `figure`. If not you can remove it.

Active the commented second `\caption`, if you want so see what happens, if you're using more than one `\caption` in such a `figure`.

[image]

I've used `\RenewDocumentEnvironment` because it supports easy usage of the environment arguments in the *end* part of the declaration. And you could also add additional optional arguments to the new `figure` environment to use them for the optional arguments of the internal `captionbeside` environment. `\RenewDocumentEnvironment` is not limited to only one optional argument.