# Display both short and long title in a caption with subcaption and report

Tags: captions

Almost a duplicate of [Display short title and long title (both) in a caption with subcaption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353986/display-short-title-and-long-title-both-in-a-caption-with-subcaption/354053?noredirect=1#comment1049070_354053)

But they use KOMA and I use `report` class. I understand for me it should work simply with just:

```
\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\makeatletter
\let\x@caption\caption % original \caption
\def\x@@caption[#1]#2{\x@caption[{#1}]{#1 --- #2}} % with optional arg
\def\x@@@caption#1{\x@caption[{#1}]{#1}} % without optional arg
\def\caption{\@ifnextchar[\x@@caption\x@@@caption} % new \caption
\makeatother
```

But it doesn't. Although I get a warning (as expected) `` Package caption Warning: Forced redefinition of \caption since the unsupported(!) package option `compatibility=false' was given. ``, the resulting document does not display the optional text.

Is this some recent update of the `caption` package that no longer works with the given code ? Following, is a really *minimal* working example. I haven't included subcaption yet or any other customisations that may break it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

    \makeatletter
    \let\x@caption\caption % original \caption
    \def\x@@caption[#1]#2{\x@caption[{#1}]{#1 --- #2}} % with optional arg
    \def\x@@@caption#1{\x@caption[{#1}]{#1}} % without optional arg
    \def\caption{\@ifnextchar[\x@@caption\x@@@caption} % new \caption
    \makeatother


\begin{document}
\listoffigures


\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption[Optional]{mandatory}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caption package has some `\AtBeginDocument` hook that detect if the `\caption` command has changed from its original definition.

A workaround is to also make the redefinition of `\caption` `\AtBeginDocument`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[compatibility=false]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\makeatletter
\let\x@caption\caption % original \caption
\long\def\x@@caption[#1]#2{\x@caption[{#1}]{#1 --- #2}}% with optional arg
\def\x@@@caption#1{\x@caption[{#1}]{#1}}% without optional arg
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\caption{\@ifnextchar[\x@@caption\x@@@caption}% new \caption
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption[Optional]{mandatory}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The \AtBeginDocument also fixes the [compatibility=false] requirement.  Interestingly, modifying \caption@caption causes it to hang.

Comment: It works ! So easy haha! Why did none of the others mention this, I wonder... What do you mean with `modifying \caption@caption` ?

Comment: The caption package replaces \caption with \caption@caption, so I thought why not just replace \caption@caption?  Looking closer at the code, the caption package compares the definition of \caption with a long list of possible variations, and generates an error if your \caption isn't on the list.  If they repeat the test after replacement, and replace again...

Comment: coming again to this, it seems I have some captions with multiple paragraphs (each refers to subfigures). Before the above modifications, I had blank line to make paragraph. Now, it fails with `Runaway argument`. It works if I replace blank line with `\\ `. What do you think ? Should I just use `\\ ` ?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă I edited the answer. The only thing that changed is that `\x@@caption` is now a `\long\def` instead of just `\def`. TeX doesn't allow paragraph breaks inside `\def`s, unless you make them `\long`. But be careful, you cannot put paragraph breaks in the optional argument of the `\caption`. More specifically, the caption entry that goes to the List of Figures cannot have paragraph breaks. This is only allowed in the caption that goes below the figure.